# How can this if statement be simplified?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, std-pair, code-inspection

I am using CLion IDE to code my C++ project. Sometimes it happens that the IDE tries to be more intelligent than me and gives me suggestions. I have a simple problem during code inspection (by CLion). It says the following code can be simplified, even though I believe it is the most simple form I can think of :

**Code :**

```
    if (node.first >= 0 && node.first <= 45 &&
    node.second >= 0 && node.second <= 30)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
```

Assume node is of type `std::pair<int, int>`

The suggestion I get from the CLion IDE is the following:

**Code Inspection comments :**

```
Inspection info: This inspection finds the part of the code that can be simplified, e.g. constant conditions, identical if branches, pointless boolean expressions, etc.
```

Do you think this can be simplified more ?

Comment: Do you have an `else` clause?

Comment: You're sure the members aren't an unsigned type?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to deduce that one of these conditions always / never holds?

Comment: why "assume" node is of type std::pair<int,int>?

Comment: These inspections normally come with an option to refactor the code into the alternate form. Are you sure it's not giving you that option? In fact, [it does for me with this example](https://i.imgur.com/7Bk2vzv.png), indeed rewriting it to the form in the answer.

Comment: @chris Thanks for this intel. I now realize that CLion does more than what I actually thought it does. This is impressive. Forgive me for my dumbness. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CLion is hinting at you that this bit...

```
if (node.first >= 0 && node.first <= 45 &&
    node.second >= 0 && node.second <= 30)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

could just be re-written as

```
return node.first  >= 0 && node.first  <= 45 &&
       node.second >= 0 && node.second <= 30;
```

Since an expression used as a condition in a control statement obviously has a natural conversion to true and false.

Comment: You are right. I have an else statement like this. But the IDE only highlighted the if statement for the warning and it excluded the else statement. So I believed it was a problem only with the if statement and posted it here to comply with [Minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: @ArunKumar Did you confirm that you still get the highlight even if you remove the `else` part? If not, then you did not post a reproducible example. If so, this answer is not the right answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I realize that this answer is 100 % right for my problem. I did not post the else statement before thinking that the problem was only with the if statement. But later when I realized the true problem, I edited my post.